# Different role for free and pro users in wordpress without using bbpress

Tags: admin, users, user-roles

I have the condition where all users are created by admin and user name and password given to them. When the created user login than pro user can create post, upload files, edit their profile but the free user only can create and edit their profile no upload the files and no post. Also the pro users post must be approved by admin than only visible to public. What is the best role for the free user and pro user in this condition ? No use of bbpress

Comment: The description of your problem makes that default author role and default suscriptor role are enough for your requeriments. Authors can edit their profiles, create and publish content, upload files, .... Suscriptor only can edit their profiles. I don't understand how bbPress is involved here.

Comment: I also need the field in users profile to add their profile image not from gravatar just upload button..

Comment: How could I know that if you didn't say it? Be accurate in your question, if not you will never get the answer you are looking for. There are plugins to add local avatars (no gravatar) in user profiles, you can try them or user as base to create your own plugin for that.

Comment: I mean, you don't need to install a forum engine just to add avatar field to user profile.

Comment: My customer's don't know to add the gravatar and just want to add the image but i solved using plugin and next is how to remove the adminmenu and adminbar for user who are not admin on their profile page ?

Comment: Please, post another question about your new issue. One question per thread.